# How to create multiple button according to user request on QT,C++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create multiple button according to user request.
i want to reduce these lines.
I know this is wrong way to create multiple buttons because i can not add or remove button while the program is running.

```
current_positiony = (height/5)+current_positiony;
QPushButton* button2 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[9]),this);
button2 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));

current_positiony = (height/5)+current_positiony;
QPushButton* button3 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[10]),this);
button3 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));

current_positiony = (height/5)+current_positiony;
QPushButton* button4 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[11]),this);
button4 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));

current_positiony = 0;
QPushButton* button5 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[12]),this);
button5 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint((width-(width/3)),current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));

current_positiony = (height/5)+current_positiony;
QPushButton* button6 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[13]),this);
button6 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint((width-(width/3)),current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));

current_positiony = (height/5)+current_positiony;
QPushButton* button7 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[14]),this);
button7 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint((width-(width/3)),current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));

current_positiony = (height/5)+current_positiony;
QPushButton* button8 = new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[15]),this);
button8 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint((width-(width/3)),current_positiony),QSize((width/3),(height/5))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily in any method (possibly a slot connected to signal triggered by user) of your custom widget (or whatever you are using) class. Small example:

```
_buttonIdx= ???  // you need to keep track of number of buttons you already have, e.g. make it a private field
_current_positiony = (height/5)+_current_positiony; // note that _current_positiony should also be your class private field
QPushButton* button= new QPushButton(QString::fromStdString(message_button_name[_buttonIdx]),this);
button->setObjectName(message_button_name[_buttonIdx]);  // this is important if you want to find that button using findChild.
```

[findChild docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.12/qobject.html#findChild)

Later somewhere else in the code (of the same class), if you want to access this button, you can just do

```
QPushButton *button = this->findChild<QPushButton*>(message_button_name[idx].c_str());  // idx - num of the button you need
```

Alternatively, you can keep `std::vector<QPushButton*>` as a private field, but QT already does it for you behind the scenes, if you pass `this` as new QT object parent.